# Json Schema Validation - Conditional Verification

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

Is it possible to verify a JSON schema using AND conditions between two elements?

I have an example where I need to verify property A only if property B has value "true".
for example:

```
{
    "A":"verify me only if B is true",
    "B": "false"
}
```

in this case, A should not be verified at all.

I can verify A or B separately but don't know how to link the two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create two alternatives using anyOf.

In the first alternative, B is an enumeration with just the value true, A is verified, and presumably you want both A and B required. In the second alternative, B is not (an enumeration with just the value true), and A is not verified.